# Open Power BI report in-app browser within an iOS app

Tags: ios, swift, powerbi

We have a requirement for integrating power BI reports that should be viewed on a browser inside an iOS app. The issue we are having is that the user has to login to Power BI the first time they open a report. Post that, viewing any other reports work until the session is alive.

The user is already logged into the iOS app with the same credentials so is there a easy-way to enable single sign on from the iOS app so the login to power BI doesn't come up again for the user?

Thanks
Deepak